# Items not returned from a list

Tags: sql, select, where-in

I have a list of items that is 860 items long.  When i execute the query: `select * from tableA where item in (... items ...)` I get 858 items.  I would like to know the 2 items in the list that are not in tableA.

NOT returns all of the items in the table that are not in the list, I want all the items in the list that are not in the table.

Comment: which database are you using? mysql? postgres? oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you convert your list into a temp table (there are a ton of udfs floating around that you can use ex: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/06/sql-server-udf-function-to-convert-list-to-table/)

Once you have your temp table `#List`, you can do the following;

```
CREATE TABLE #List
(
  [ListItem] INT
)

SELECT
    *
FROM
    #List AS l
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tableA AS t
ON
    t.[Item] = l.[ListItem]
WHERE
    t.[Item] IS NULL
```

See it in action: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61259/items-not-returned-from-a-list

Answer (score 1):

Based on my original understanding of the question, I suggested to just add the keyword NOT

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE item NOT IN (... items ...)
```

But as per the comment the above will not return what you want.  The original question was edited to include this new infomration.

So, you need to get your data from your WHERE clause into a form that is queryable.  Here is one way to do it where I create an additional table named "items" and have INSERT statements to place each item into this items table.  Since I do not have access to your data, I am going to use integers for the items and set it up with a smaller amount of data.

```
--Set up some sample data
CREATE TABLE tableA(item INT PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO tableA SELECT 1
INSERT INTO tableA SELECT 2
INSERT INTO tableA SELECT 3
INSERT INTO tableA SELECT 4
INSERT INTO tableA SELECT 9
INSERT INTO tableA SELECT 10

SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE item IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE item NOT IN (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)

-- Create a table and insert all the 860 items from your where clause
CREATE TABLE items(item INT)
INSERT INTO items SELECT 0
INSERT INTO items SELECT 1
INSERT INTO items SELECT 2
INSERT INTO items SELECT 3
INSERT INTO items SELECT 4
INSERT INTO items SELECT 5
INSERT INTO items SELECT 6

-- Want to find a query that returns all of the items in the newly created items table
-- that are not in the original tableA (in this example, the values returned are 0,5,6)
SELECT * FROM items WHERE item NOT IN (SELECT item FROM tableA)
```

Comment: that returns all of the items in the table that are not in the list, not all the items in the list that are not in the table

Comment: Your problem is not well defined.  tableA could contain 858 records that all have the same value for their item field and you would have 858 records returned.  The problem as written assumes that there are 2 items in the list that are not in tableA, but there could be many more.

Comment: table A contains hundreds of thousands of items.  Item is unique.

Comment: Is "items" actually a list or is it the resultset of another query?

Comment: its an actual list `in (itemA, itemB, ...)`

Comment: I think that you need to get those list items into a table.  How is the list created now?  How do you know there are 860 items in it?  The problem as I understand it is to SELECT item FROM (... items ...) WHERE  item NOT IN (SELECT item from tableA).

Comment: -1 This answer completely misses the mark. The question is quite clear is to its requirements, and this isn't helpful at all.

Comment: @Bohemian I initially did not fully understand the question, but I then attempted to fully flesh out an answer which you see above.  I appreciate that you are indicating that my answer is not helpful, but could you provide some more constructive criticism please?  I believe that I reduced the original problem into a sample which I then solved.  It is not clear to me why you are indicating that my answer missed the mark.  I see that you have been a member for many years and have accumulated lots of reputation so would appreciate any guidance that you could provide.  Thank you.

Comment: OK. I've removed the -1. I see you've edited the answer considerably. Essentially, you need some kind of reference table that has all the values. Your answer uses a table. A better choice would be a *temporary* table. Another, still better choice, would be to use a table where you knew all the values existed (not provided in question, but you could have suggested using a lookup table if one existed) with a fairly simple join. Your solution would work, but it is hardly elegant. Try to avoid creating tables just to run queries unless there really is no other way (sometimes there is no other way)

Comment: @Bohemian Thank you.  I had asked in a comment for clarification on whether "items" was a list or the result of another query.  I agree it would be better if the values already existed in a queryable form.  I really appreciate your feedback.